# Cant get localhost working on WAMP with Google Drive

Tags: php, windows, apache, wamp

I know this has been asked 10k times but the solutions elsewhere do not seem to be working for me.

Im running WAMP 2.2 with apache 2.4.2 and trying to set DocumentRoot to a different folder than the default one

http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ works just fine but I cannot load `localhost` and keep getting:

[image]

If I try `localhost:8080` I get:

[image]

#### httpd.conf

```
ServerName localhost

# Deny access to the entirety of your server's filesystem. You must
# explicitly permit access to web content directories in other 
# <Directory> blocks below.
#

<Directory />
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Require all denied
</Directory>

....


DocumentRoot "C:/Users/wesley.smith/Google Drive/"
<Directory "C:/Users/wesley.smith/Google Drive/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    # onlineoffline tag - do not remove
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

In my host file, I have uncommented the below:

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
    127.0.0.1       localhost
    ::1             localhost
```

I have skype installed which uses port 80 so I went to `Tools -> Options -> Advanced -> Connections` and unchecked the box "use port 80 and 443 as alternative". Then I turned skype off just for good measure

If I run `Apache-> Service-> test port 80` I get:

[image]

I can also use php from the command line just fine:
[image]

#### I've tried everything I've found online to no avail, what else could be wrong?

Comment: Did you restart your pc after turning off skype?

Comment: @atefth I did not restart my PC but did restart WAMP. When I run the test, itshows that port 80 is now being used by the server. Prior to my change the test showed it was being used by skype

Comment: can you use PHP from the command line?

Comment: @You Yep, I can indeed, added screenshot

Comment: does Apache have folder permission to view `C:/Users/wesley.smith/Google Drive/`? On linux systems, Apache needs execute rights for every folder up the tree to root.

Comment: @JeffPuckettII this is on a windows machine where IIUC apache runs as a service and automatically has permissions of 777 for most/all paths

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the document root block by this...

```
<Directory /> 
    Options Indexes 
    FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all 
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And do a Apache restart.

Comment: Im not sure this would do what I  need as I need the root to be at `C:/Users/wesley.smith/Google Drive/`. Additionally, the `# onlineoffline tag - do not remove` must remain in the file as it is used by wamp's `onlineOffline.php` to switch between `Require all granted` and `Require local` when putting the server online or offline. That said, I tried your suggestion just for grins but got the exact same issue :(

Comment: Can you please check the apache error logs and see what it says ?

Comment: Actually, thank you but I resolved the issue via the answer on the duplicate question. It turns out that Google Drive creates its folder with a non-standard permission structure (the folder does not inherit permissions from its parent folder). Manually setting the permissions to inherit fixed the problem

Comment: Good to know you were able to solve it & thanks for the update :-)

Comment: **This is a VERY dangerous suggested change** Before suggesting such changes you really ought to understand what effect a change like this has on you systems security. It only goes to show a complete lack of understanding of Apache

Comment: I understand but he's doing his test on local machine.